# Retrieve child data as array or iteration in Firebase Database

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a child node that looks like this:

[image]

and I want to get the data and put the userID in the from of array. So that I can iterate and write data in those userID. However currently I am unable to figure out how to read from the database and get the userID into an array.

I only want the `userID` in the array. Where the node is like (friends/"key"/userID).

here is the json -

```
"friends" : {
      "-KVFPNlR76oIsnvdeuEr" : {
        "userID" : "QbfjBiy7yhTT9Bi9H8dLNv7h0A02",
        "userName" : "michael s speed",
        "userPhoto" : ""
      },
      "-KVFPNmS42zrefrGKM2L" : {
        "userID" : "QbfjBiy7yhTT9Bi9H8dLNv7h0A02",
        "userName" : "michael s speed",
        "userPhoto" : ""
      },
      "-KVQWEH4xY1-88vyUmKd" : {
        "userID" : "ZEBXY8WmQaWIza4L2ptSPpKUQGY2",
        "userName" : "michael dinesh",
        "userPhoto" : ""
      },
      "-KVVeqLtEji4b1ZW3gcj" : {
        "userID" : "Hvf69rGDTsgQgBLdnUcg5uGZSgB2",
        "userName" : "rina bora",
        "userPhoto" : ""
      }
    },
```

Comment: anyone. can help me?

Comment: I didn't understand your question or problem. Look that: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) Is it enough?